# Azure service fabric does not cancel with lots of tasks

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I'm trying to test out various performance aspects of Azure Service Fabric to understand how it all works and have hit against some problems when cancelling a service.

In one particular test, I create 101 tasks, 50 reading a queue, 50 writing a queue and 1 showing progress and reporting it.

When the service gets stopped, for example just re-deploying the application I can see the cancellation token gets the request and some tasks cancel, but I see a lot of events in the event viewer basically saying

```
AsyncCalloutAdapter-22542743: end delegate threw an exception
   System.OperationCanceledException: Operation canceled. --->     System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Operation aborted (Exception from   HRESULT: 0x80004004 (E_ABORT))
   at System.Fabric.Interop.NativeRuntime.IFabricStateReplicator2.EndReplicate(IFabricAsyncOperationContext context)
   at System.Fabric.Interop.AsyncCallOutAdapter2`1.Finish(IFabricAsyncOperationContext context, Boolean expectedCompletedSynchronously)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

The only way to get this back is to either reset the local cluster.

When using a fewer number of tasks it all seems to work ok.

This is all using a local development cluster.

Comment: Are you re-using the ServiceProxy reference for all the calls ? If you re-use the ServiceProxy, and SF moves a service/activates another primary after you've gotten the ServiceProxy, but before you do the call, it'll fail, since the service address has changed then.

Comment: I'm not calling any other service - I'm just doing some perf testing.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misread your initial question.

Comment: @NickRandell did you ever figure the issue? If not, could you post some of your code that does this performance testing? I am curious if it can be replicated.